# Symbols in a scatterplot with two kinds of points ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I want to draw a scatterplot with two kinds of plots first points represent averages with sd error bars

```
sou <- data.frame (Source=c("Copepods","Macroalgae","MPB"),md13C=rnorm(3,-18,5),sd13C=rnorm(3,5,2),md15N=rnorm(3,3,2),sd15N=rnorm(3,0.20,0.2))

require(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(sou,aes(x=md13C, y=md15N))  
p <- p + geom_point(aes(shape=Source),
                    fill = "black",size=4,)+scale_shape_manual(values=c(21,22,23))

p <- p + geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = md13C-sd13C,xmax = md13C+sd13C),height=0)
p <- p + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = md15N-sd15N,ymax = md15N+sd15N),width=0)+theme_bw()
p
```

this graph have filled points with shapes I selected, now I will add the second set of points

```
con <- data.frame(FeedingGroup=rep(c("deposivore", "omnivore","ectosymbionts","deposit feeder",
                                        "scavenger","predator","filter feeder","predator/scavenger"),each=6),
                 Site=rep(c("Creek","Faro","Isla"),each=16),
                 d13C=rnorm(48,-18,5),d15N=rnorm(48,5,5))


p <-p +theme(legend.justification=c(0,1), legend.position=c(0,1),legend.title=element_blank())
brk <- c(unique(as.character(sou$Source)),unique(as.character(con$FeedingGroup)))
p + geom_point(data=con, aes(x=d13C, y=d15N,color=Site,shape=FeedingGroup)) + scale_shape_manual(breaks=brk,values=c(21,22,23,0,1,2,5,6,7,9,10,11,3,4,8,12,13))+guides(colour=FALSE)
```

the problem is that the shapes (symbols) assigned previously to the first group change, and I need the filled symbols for first group of points and hollow symbols for the second group.

And there is another problem: the unfilled symbols appears with concentric shapes!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the description of `?discrete_scale`, you will find the following for the `breaks` argument: "This parameter does not affect in any way how the data is scaled - it only affects the appearance of the legend." If you read the next line, it says that `limits` is "A character vector specifying the data range for the scale. and the default order of their display in guides." So you want to use `limits` instead of `breaks`:

```
scale_shape_manual(limits=brk, values=c(21,22,23,0,1,2,5,6,7,9,10,11,3,4,8,12,13))
```

Comment: Thanks, also the unfilled symbols appears with concentric shapes, do you know why?

Comment: It is because of the differen sizes used in the plot. In the legend you get all symbols in size=1 and size=4. I don't know how to avoid that.

Comment: I added that problem to the original question, to see if somebody knows how to solve it.